# How to setState with a variable as the key?

Tags: reactjs

How to setState with a variable like the following:

```
this.handler = (field) => {

this.setState({field:'value'})

}
```

Please help I am having trouble doing it.

Comment: use `[]` for dynamic key.

Answer (score 1):

this will solve your issue

```
this.handler = (field) => {
  this.setState(
     { [field] :'value'}
  );
}
```

Comment: How about if the field is nested do you know how I would do that?

Comment: nested also you can convey the same `this.setState({ [field.keyName] :'value'});`